# Express $X$ as a sum of two independent random variables

Tags: probability, generating-functions

We are given an integer $r \geq 2$ which is not a prime number and a random variable $X$ such that $P(X=k) = 1/r$ for $k= 0,1,...,r-1$, and $P(X=k) = 0$ otherwise. Express $X$ as a sum of two independent, non-constant random variables. I know I need to use probablity-generating functions somehow, but I am not sure how. How do I do that?

Comment: @lulu I have edited my post, I hope it is clearer now.

Comment: Hint:  for $r=4$, say, let $Y$ be $0,1$ with equal probability and let $Z$ be $0,2$ with equal probability.

Comment: @lulu How can you guarantee that $Y$ and $Z$ are independent? Also if you have a solution using generating functions (this problem is given in generating functions section) i'd love to hear it too.

Comment: Let $Y$ be the toss of a fair penny with a $0$ on one side and a $1$ on the other.  Let $Z$ be the toss of a fair dime with a $0$ on one side and a $2$ on the other.  This problem doesn't seem related to generating functions to me, though of course I might be missing a connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $r\ge2$ is not prime, write $r=ab$ with integers $a,\,b\ge2$. Then take $X=Y+Z$ [with](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) $Y\sim\mathcal{U}(0,\,a-1),\,Z/a\sim\mathcal{U}(0,\,b-1)$ independent. Equivalently, define $Z:=a\left\lfloor\frac{X}{a}\right\rfloor,\,Y:=X-Z$.

Comment: Yes, I just came up myself with this solution as well (the 'equvilently' part). Thank you!